# How can I synchronize a tick() and render() methods in a animation loop?

Tags: java, animation, game-loop

I am making a animation with java graphics 2D, based on a game loop(tick and render).
I want to make a ball walk along a curved line, so I am using a FatteningPathIterator to obtain the points from the Curved line and save them in a ArrayList.

Than I reference this group of points to a "Ball" Object

My original idea is o use the tick method in "Ball" to set a new value for the variables x and y, but when I do this the render() method seems to not synchronize with the current values of X and Y. Would it be because of Thread synchronization?

If I try to update the x and Y positions inside the render() method in "Ball", the ball moves along the path but the program starts to get slower and slower.

The following code are the classes:

1 - Animation.java

```
public class Animation extends Canvas implements Runnable {

public static final int WIDTH = 1024, HEIGHT =  WIDTH/12*9 ;
private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;

private Handler handler;    
private Line line;

public Animation(){
     new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT,"Test", this);
     handler = new Handler();

     line = new Line();
     handler.addObject(new Ball(500,500,"Bola",handler,10,line.points()));  


}





public void run() {

    this.requestFocus();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double  amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 250/amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;

    while(running){

        long now = System.nanoTime(); 
        delta += (now-lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;

        while(delta >= 1){
            tick();

            delta--;
        }
        if(running) 
            render();

        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer >1000){

            timer += 1000;
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}

public synchronized void start(){

        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

public synchronized void stop(){

        try{
            thread.join();
            running = false;

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
private void tick(){

    handler.tick();

}

private void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    rh.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);     



    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);
    g2d.setColor(Color.white);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    line.render(g2d);
    handler.render(g);

    g.dispose();
    g2d.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new Animation(); 
 }}
```

2 - Window.java

```
public class Ball extends Object {

ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
int index = 0;


private int raius;
public Ball(int x, int y, String id, Handler handler, int raius, ArrayList<Point> points) {
    super(x, y, id,handler);
    this.raius = raius;
    this.points = points;
    System.out.println(points);
    velX = 5;
    x = 0;

    System.out.println("Here");
}

public void tick() {
    index++;
    if (index>=points.size()) {
        index=0;
    }
    x = points.get(index).x;
    y  = points.get(index).y;
}   
public void render(Graphics g) {


    g.setColor(Color.red);

    g.fillOval(x, y, raius, raius);

}}
```

3 - Object.java

```
public abstract class Object {

protected int x,y;
protected String id;
protected int velX, velY;
protected Handler handler;

public Object(int x, int y, String id, Handler handler){

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = id;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

public abstract void tick();
public abstract void render(Graphics g);

public void setX(int x){
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y){
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public int getY(){
    return y;
}

public void setId(String id){
    this.id = id;       
}

public String getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setVelX(int velX){
    this.velX = velX;
}

public void setVelY( int velY){
    this.velY = velY;
}

public int getVelX(){
    return velX;
}

public int getVelY(){
    return velY;
}}
```

4 - Line.java

```
public class Line {

FlatteningPathIterator iter;
Shape shape;
ArrayList<Point> points;
CubicCurve2D cubcurve = new CubicCurve2D.Float(30, 400, 150, 400, 200, 500, 350, 450);

public Line(){
     shape = cubcurve;
     iter = new FlatteningPathIterator( cubcurve.getPathIterator(new AffineTransform()), 0.5);
     points=new ArrayList<Point>();
     float[] coords=new float[6];
     while (!iter.isDone()) {
         iter.currentSegment(coords);
         int x=(int)coords[0];
         int y=(int)coords[1];
         points.add(new Point(x,y));
         iter.next();
     }
     System.out.println(points);
}


public ArrayList<Point> points(){
    return points;
}

public void render(Graphics g){


    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    BasicStroke bs3 = new BasicStroke(4, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,
            BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL);

    g2d.setStroke(bs3);     
    g2d.setColor(Color.blue);       
    g2d.draw(cubcurve);

}}
```

5- Ball.java

```
public class Ball extends Object {

ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
int index = 0;


private int raius;
public Ball(int x, int y, String id, Handler handler, int raius, ArrayList<Point> points) {
    super(x, y, id,handler);
    this.raius = raius;
    this.points = points;
    System.out.println(points);
    velX = 5;
    x = 0;

    System.out.println("Here");
}

public void tick() {
    index++;
    if (index>=points.size()) {
        index=0;
    }
    x = points.get(index).x;
    y  = points.get(index).y;
}   
public void render(Graphics g) {


    g.setColor(Color.red);

    g.fillOval(x, y, raius, raius);

}}
```

Comment: it is more likely the problem is because the values aren't being set correctly, but since there's no example code of what you tried, its hard to say.

Comment: Its impossible to tell when you do not show how the objects are actually used and from which thread which methods are called. I suspect that your code has concurrency problems, with some code running on the main thread and render being called asynchronously on Swing's EDT. Since it doesn't look like you actually do super cpu intensive work I would recommend to do everything on the EDT, possibly triggered through a Timer.

Comment: Thank you guys, I am afraid of putting everything on the EDT, because latter I'll expand to more lines and balls. I am going to post the whole code on the description